# formalchemy date field rendering

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, formalchemy

Given a column called 'birthday' in my model that I declare like this:

```
birthday = Column(Date)
```

I'm trying to display it as a row in my form. However, I have to respect the French standard that goes like "Year" "Day" "Month" instead of "Month" "Day" "Year".

So far the closest I got to it is :

```
fs.birthday.set(html=[('lang', 'fr')])
```

which does display the names of the months in French rather than English, but is there a way to easily change the display order of the elements without witting a custom renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I found for this was to reorder the fields using JQuery:

```
 // Reorder date fields
  function reorder( dateFieldId ) {

    var grp = $('#'+dateFieldId).children();
    var cnt = grp.length;

    var temp = grp[0];
    grp[0] = grp[1];
    grp[1] = temp;

    $(grp).remove();
    $('#'+dateFieldId).append($(grp));
  }
```